# T-SQL HASHBYTES function and collation

Tags: t-sql, function, hash, sql-server-2012, collation

I am working with SQL Server 2012 and have table with field defined as:

> NVARCHAR(32)

but need to store in it

> NVARCHAR(1024)

value and I am not able to change the column length.

I have a procedure that will populate this field. At the same time, it will "do something" if there is field with such value and "do nothing" if there is field with such value.

To solve the issue with the length I've decided to use [HashBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174415%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) function as follows:

```
DECLARE @HashThis nvarchar(1024);
SELECT @HashThis = CONVERT(nvarchar(1024),'dslfdkjLK85kldhnv$n000#knf');
SELECT HASHBYTES('SHA1', @HashThis);
GO
```

I have read that depending on your database collation you could have different hash return for same values. So, is there a way to specify a collation just for the function in order no to depend by database collation.

Also, is there something wrong with my idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT HashBytes('SHA1', CONVERT(nvarchar,'вася пупкин' collate Cyrillic_General_CS_AS)) ;
```